# Exported Function isn't a Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Not sure why it's not viewing this as a function:

**impl.js**

```
export default function(callback){
    return callback();
};
```

**test.js**

```
import {myModule} from '../../src/impl.js'
import {expect} from 'chai';

const module = myModule;

describe('', () => {

    it('should callback when resolve is invoked', () => {
        module(resolve => {
            resolve('test');
            }).then(value => {
                expect(value).to.equal('test');
            });
    });

});
```

Error: `TypeError: module is not a function`

Comment: yea I couldnt' think of a good title but just changed it, hope that's better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`module` isn't a `function` because where it receives its value, `myModule`, also isn't a `function`.

And, that is because you aren't using quite the correct syntax to `import` the `export default`. For that, you'll want to remove the braces around `myModule`:

```
import myModule from '../../src/impl.js'
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

> Syntax
>
> `import *defaultMember* from *"module-name"*;`

---

With the braces, the `import` will match a particular `export` by its name.

> ```
> import { myModule } from '...';
> ```
>
> Corresponds to either:
>
> ```
> export let myModule = ...;
> ```
>
> ```
> export function myModule() { ... };
> ```

And, `impl.js` doesn't export anything actually named `myModule`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an export with name `myModule`. You only have a default export.

Either use a named export

```
export function myModule() { ... }
```

or import the the module properly

```
import myModule from '...';
```

---

See the [`export` documentation on MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Comment: great I changed it but now I get resolve is not a function in impl.js in my implementation of my function there.  I figured since I was sending in resolve => {...} when calling my impl function that it's passing a function so that I can call it once in my impl function

Comment: @WTF No value is being provided for `resolve`. Using `return callback(() => {});` in `impl.js` will start you toward your goal.

Comment: @WTF: As Jonathon said, you are not passing anything anything to the callback (`return callback();`), so the error is correct.

Comment: yea I guess I don't fully understand resolve => then..arrow function, thought I did or I don't understand how to work with it in terms of calling back to it

Comment: @WTF: `resolve => {...}` defines a function that accepts one argument, just like `function(resolve) { ... }`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions . *"I don't understand how to work with it in terms of calling back to it"* Calling an arrow function is no different than calling any other function.

Comment: what would () => {} do, return a function that takes no params and does nothing?

Comment: @WTF: Yes, just like `function() {}`.

Comment: I've been looking at arrow function docs, so I guess I still don't understand what resolve => { resolve('hi) } is doing.  I guess it's resolve is calling itself

Comment: @WTF: The same as `function(resolve) {  resolve('hi) }`. It defines a function that accepts a function as argument and calls it with the argument `'hi'`. `resolve` is a *parameter*. It's almost the same as you have in `impl.js`.

Comment: thx!  I was definitely reading that arrow function wrong in my head.  So the (resolve) => the parens is optional it looks like hence just resolve =>

Comment: so then why would you callback with () => {} which is an anonymous function that takes no params and has no implementation?

Comment: oh I think I get it!  duh  Since the value is hard coded, the 'hi' there is no need to specify anything in the () because it'd be ignored in this case anyway

Comment: @WTF: `()=>{}` was just used as example to make `resolve` refer to a function and so calling `resolve(...)` wouldn't throw an error. Of course you have to provide the correct implementation.

Comment: one more question.  Since I'm sending in a function (the resolve => { resolve('hi')}) intoto my impl function as a param.  Then doesn't my impl function already know that it is a callback function and I can just call it?  It's a callback...still don't get why I'd need to add () =>